# Passing multiple Selected dropdownlist Value/options Into Sql Query using classic asp

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have requirement, to select multiple(more than one/two/three) options/values from combobox/dropdownlist, these values  i need to pass through sql query, can you please help me on this at earliest.

```vb
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="f10pt">
<td width=90px><b>Country:</td>
<td><select multiple name="Locale" class="f8pt" style="width:80px;">
<option value="">All Locales</option>
<%
SQLstr="Select country_id,country_text from dbo.country with (NOLOCK) order by       country_id Asc"
DocDBRecords.open SQLstr, DOCDB, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
if not DocDBRecords.bof And not DocDBRecords.eof Then 
  Do While Not DocDBRecords.Eof
    Response.Write "<option value=""" & DocDBRecords("country_id") & """"
    If Len(CountryQuery)>0 Then
      If (CInt(DocDBRecords("country_id"))=CInt(CountryQuery)) Then
        Response.Write " SELECTED"
      End If
    End If
    Response.Write ">" & DocDBRecords("country_text") & "</option>"
    DocDBRecords.movenext
  Loop
End If
DocDBRecords.close
%>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Jyothi!  It would be a lot easier to help if we knew how far along you get before you get an error.  Please post code of what you've tried so far and the errors you've received.

Comment: If you want to be able to choose multiple options then you need to use `<select multiple name="Locale" class="f8pt" style="width:80px;"`

Comment: @john, I have to send multiple values selected from dropdown list to Select query to display data , Please help me at earliest, I am new to Classic Asp.

Comment: Your example above will only allow you to select one option.  You need to use `<select multiple>` rather than `<select>`.  That isn't a Classic ASP issue, it's an HTML issue.  Once you've implemented a select multiple you can try my answer below

Comment: @john, I have added select multiple attribute in the above code, but still i am not able pass two parameters to sql select statement

Answer (score 0):

You have your select multiple form element.  If you select more than one option then the options would be sent as a comma separated string.

You can then do something like this

```
selectname = Request.Form("yourselectname")
selectarray = split(selectname,",")
For Each item In selectarray
    sql ="Insert into yourtable (yourfield) values('" & item & "')"
    conn.Execute sql
Next
```

If you want to pass your values into a select query one option is to use the VBS replace function to change commas to "or where countryid=" eg

```
idstring = replace(Request.Form("countryid"),","," or where countryid = ")
sql="Select country_id,country_text from dbo.country where countryid = "& idstring
```

If your form is on a public facing website I'd strongly recommend you have some sort of regex function which your form data has to pass through before it's sent to the database, otherwise you leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @JyothiGowda Could you add your code to your original question that way you can format it and make it easier to read. Comments are not suited for big blocks of code.

Comment: @Lankymart please check the above code and reply me soon